# unable to insepct field which have dynamic id

Tags: selenium

I have to inspect this field for automation in selenium using Java, but the id field is changing in every new session.These are the outer HTML for both dates which have used hasdatepicker plugin:-

Comment: Please share the URL or HTML

Comment: First field:-                                                     <input type="text" ng-model="pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effStrtTsUI" size="30" customdatepicker="" 
required="" class="ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="dp1507178659034">


Second field:-                                        <input type="text" ng-model="pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effEndTsUI" size="30" customdatepicker="" 
required="" class="ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="dp1507184165531">

Comment: what u want to locate in it

Comment: there are two fields...You can find the html in above comment named first field and sacond field

Comment: i have to inspect it for xpath actually for my automation script

Comment: then i tried using id for it but it is dynamic and is changing in each session

Comment: You want to enter some text in textboxes

Comment: I thinks this is not changing id="dp150717

Comment: i didnt get you .sory please help me with the same

Comment: no it is changing every session it is dynamic

Comment: Ok let me try it. Let me know one thing each time there is first field and seconnd fields appeared

Comment: Wait i ll give u every thing in brief in my next comment

Comment: First field is effective start date whose html is:-    <input type="text" ng-model="pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effStrtTsUI" size="30" customdatepicker="" 
required="" class="ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="dp1507178659034">

Comment: Second field is effective end date:-       <input type="text" ng-model="pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effEndTsUI" size="30" customdatepicker="" 
required="" class="ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="dp1507184165531">

Comment: Both the fields have dynamic ids which is changing each and every time.

Comment: Ok , it means this field are always there

Comment: AND hasdatepicker plugin is used by the developer for this .

Comment: Yeahh exactly,anything else which is not clear from my side??

Comment: Try this -  //input[starts-with(@id,'dp')]//*[@ng-model='pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effStrtTsUI'] for 1st field. Let me know your outcome.

Comment: @saad no it is not working it is coming as unable to locate

Comment: //input[starts-with(@id,'dp')][@ng-model='pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effEndTsUI'] What about this ??

Comment: Don't put HTML and code in comments, edit it into your question so it can be properly formatted and found by others more easily.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As per your HTML as below

```
First Field -  <input type="text" ng-model="pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effStrtTsUI" size="30" customdatepicker="" required="" class="ng-pristine  hasDatepicker ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="dp1507178659034"> 

Second Field-  <input type="text" ng-model="pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effEndTsUI" size="30" customdatepicker="" required="" class="ng-pristine hasDatepicker ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="dp1507184165531">
```

you can try this xpaths:

for first field:

```
//input[contains(@id,'dp1507')][1]

 or 

//*[contains(text(),'First Field')]/input[1]
```

for second field:

```
//input[contains(@id,'dp1507')][2]

or 

//*[contains(text(),'First Field')]/input[2]
```

Remember please change the text "First Field" with actual text

Comment: @Kiratdeep Singh try this and check

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

1st Field-

`//input[starts-with(@id,'dp')][@ng-model='pointsBank.poin‌​tsBankConfig.effStrt‌​TsUI']`

2nd Field-

`//input[starts-with(@id,'dp')][@ng-model='pointsBank.pointsBankConfig.effEndTsUI']`